# Mostrar resultado cero cuando record no presente

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Tengo dos tablas:

students

```
s_id
s_laname
s_mname
s_grupo
```

horas

```
id
s_id
horas
fecha
grupo
```

Cada vez que un estudiante participa a una clase se le agrega las horas por ejemplo 5.

Ejemplo de insert:

```
INSERT INTO horas (s_id, horas, fecha, grupo)
VALUES (145, 5, 2020-11-30, 11);
```

Necesito una select que me regrese todos los estudiantes de ese grupo y con a la par las horas brindadas en ese rango de fechas y si no han participado ponga uno cero o un NULL

He conseguido ayudas y puedo tener los NULL pero no se como sumar las horas de cada estudiante

```
SELECT students.s_lname, horas.horas 
    FROM students 
    LEFT JOIN horas ON students.s_id=horas.s_id 
           and horas.fecha >= '2020-11-01' 
           AND horas.fecha <= '2020-11-30' 
           AND horas.horas >'0' 
    WHERE students.s_grupo IN('11')


s_lname   horas 
Molina      12  
Mejías      12  
Corrales    10  
Sáenz       15  
Castro      11  
Hernandez   11  
Sáenz       12  
Hernandez   6   
Hernandez   6   
Sáenz       12  
Brizuela    NULL
Vargas      NULL
Acuña       NULL
Jiménez     NULL
López.      NULL
Jimenez     NULL
Vargas      NULL
Navarro     NULL
```

Lo que necesito es:

```
s_lname   horas 
Molina      12  
Mejías      12  
Corrales    10  
Sáenz       39  
Castro      11  
Hernandez   33
Brizuela    NULL
Vargas      NULL
Acuña       NULL
Jiménez     NULL
López       NULL
Jimenez     NULL
Vargas      NULL
Navarro     NULL
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El gran lío es que no sabemos qué tienen las tablas que mencionas, así que no sabemos de dónde sacar el cero que mencionas. Podrías por favor, [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/409270/edit) tu pregunta y añadir algunos datos de prueba?

Comment: Así de primeras, parece cosa del inner join. En ese caso quieres que salgan los alumnos siempre, así que debes usar un Left join. (Lo de la izquierda siempre, la derecha si hay relación.)

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, he modificado un poco el texto,

Comment: Qué tal @COINFEUROPEA . Es complicado proveer una respuesta si no se puede reproducir el problema. Se necesita que pongas una muestra de ambas tablas, con las columnas necesarias y una muestra de cuál es el resultado que deseas obtener.

Comment: @alfabravo he editado la pregunta hoy, creo que ahora es más fácil entender.

Comment: Hola @aeportugal, he intentado hacer más claro posible la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Reduje un poco el problema para reproducirlo más fácilmente.

*table1*

```
+---------------------+
| id | fname          |
+---------------------+
| 1  | Jose Pablo     |
| 2  | Ricardo        |
| 3  | Daniel Roberto |
| 4  | Victor         |
+----+----------------+
```

*table2*

```
+----------------------+------------+
| id | user_id | horas |   fecha    |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| 1  |   1     |   4   | 2020-11-17 |
| 2  |   3     |   5   | 2020-11-17 |
| 3  |   1     |   2   | 2020-11-18 |
| 4  |   4     |   6   | 2020-11-18 |
| 5  |   3     |   4   | 2020-11-18 |
| 6  |   1     |   6   | 2020-11-19 |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

Se puede usar [COALESCE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/coalesce/) que sustituya el valor NULL por uno definido.

```
SELECT table1.fname, COALESCE(SUM(table2.horas), 0) AS Total_horas
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.user_id=table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

También se puede usar `SUM(IFNULL(table2.hours, 0))` y da el mismo resultado.

```
+----------------+-------------+
| fname          | Total_horas |
+----------------+-------------+
| Daniel Roberto |    9        |
| Jose Pablo     |    12       |
| Ricardo        |    0        |
| Victor         |    6        |
+----------------+-------------+
```

[!] NOTA: Preferiblemente debería ser `GROUP_BY table1.id`, porque es posible tener dos estudiantes con el mismo nombre, lo cual arrojará cálculos incorrectos.

**EDITADO 1**

Cuando se agrega un WHERE, el resultado de la consulta dependerá de la condición. Si haces un `BETWEEN date1 AND date2` y un usuario no tiene registros en las fechas, el resultado omitirá los registros que no cumplan la condición, independiente que haya un LEFT JOIN.

Para que de todas formas muestre los registros que no cumplen, con un valor NULL, se puede resolver usando una subconsulta, que primero traiga los resultados que cumplen con la condición y luego confrontarlos con la tabla de usuarios.

```
SELECT table1.fname, COALESCE(SUM(B.horas), 0) AS Total_horas
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, horas 
           FROM table2 
           WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-11-17' AND '2020-11-18') AS B
ON B.user_id=table1.id 
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Y creo que ahora si trae el resultado esperado.

```
+----------------+-------------+
| fname          | Total_horas |
+----------------+-------------+
| Jose Pablo     |    6        |
| Ricardo        |    0        |
| Daniel Roberto |    9        |
| Victor         |    6        |
+----------------+-------------+
```

[!] NOTA: Si la columna es tipo DATETIME, entonces una consulta entre 2 "fechas enteras" será `'date1 00:00:00' AND 'date2 23:59:59'`

Comment: Hola @aeportugal muchas gracias, efectivamente funciona, pero si agrego un where con el rango de fechas no funciona, en el sentido que no me pone los valores a cero si los estudiantes non están en ese rango de fechas:

SELECT students.s_lname, students .s_mname, students.s_fname, students .s_grupo, COALESCE(SUM(horas.horas),0) as asistencia FROM students LEFT JOIN horas ON horas.s_id = students.s_id WHERE 1 and students.s_grupo = '11' and horas.fecha BETWEEN '2020-11-01' and '2020-11-30' GROUP by students.s_id

Comment: **PERDON**  es mi primer pregunta y aun no sé como funciona el formatear el texto.

Comment: Por ejemplo si el estudiante s_id 5 no ha participado en el rango del 1 al 30 de noviembre en la tabla horas, no aparece a cero en ese rango.
lo que estoy buscando de hacer es que la query muestre todas los estudiantes de esa clase y ponga a cero si en ese rango de fechas no ha participado a las clases.
No me he explicado bien en el texto de la pregunta

Comment: @COINFEUROPEA según los requerimientos, añadí una modificación a la consulta. Espero ahora si te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola @aeportugal, la select funciona, muchas gracias, pero esa select es de todos los estudiantes, cuando pongo la clase cursada con un **where grupo = 11** me muestra todos los estudiantes a cero.
(El campo grupo esta presente en las dos tablas).

SELECT students.s_fname, students.s_lname, COALESCE(SUM(B.horas), 0) AS Total_horas
FROM students
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s_id, horas FROM horas
           **WHERE grupo = '11'** and fecha BETWEEN '2020-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-30 23:59:59') AS B 
ON B.s_id=students.s_id 
GROUP BY students.s_id

Comment: Hola, he buscado como un loco y he llegado a la select arriba, lo único es que no encuentro como sumar las horas y no ver todos los record de cada estudiante como de imagen.